# Union of two-dimensional arrays by value

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Good afternoon.
I'm new and just learning. Please help me to solve the problem with array merging.
i hav 2 arrays

```
let arr1 = [['boss',, 'boss I.V.', '5552654','card 100'],
            ['ard',, 'ard J.B.', '3722654','card 520'],
            ['Jon',, 'Jon sviss', '394554','card 22120'],
            ['Elty B',, 'Elty Bitry B.', '12265664', 'card 9990'],
            ['Elty B.I',, 'Elty Bitry I.','3322654', 'card 002200']];

let arr2 = [['boss', 3000, 'comm1'],
            ['Elty B', 8000.500, 'comm2']];
//-------------------------------------------- 
         //I need to get:

let arrR = [[1,'boss I.V.', '5552654', 'card 100', 3000, 'comm1'],
            [2,'Elty Bitry B.', '12265664', 'card 9990', 8000.500, 'comm2']];
//--------------------------------------------
          // i made it a loop 'for':

  arr1 = arr1.filter( (item) => arr2.find((el) => el[0] === item[0])).sort();
  for (var i = 0; i<arr1.length; i++) {                    
    arr1[i].push(arr2[i][1],arr2[i][2]);
    arr1[i].splice(0,1);
    arr1[i][0] = i+1;
  }
  return arr1;
//--------------------------------------------
           //it is not right (((
```

how to do it correctly by finding by value:  " if (arr1[i][0] === arr2[k][0]) " and don't use a loop?

Comment: Please clarify the question specifying the input and what output you need!

Comment: this seems to do the trick `const res = arr2.map((e, i, a) => {
 const ra = arr1.find(item => item[0] === e[0]);
 return [i + 1, ...ra.splice(2), ...e.splice(1)];
});`

Comment: schwaber, I don't understand...

Comment: I posted it as an answer now. Easier to get the formatting right and I added a bit of explanation too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const arrR = arr2.map((e, i) => {
  const m = arr1.find(item => item[0] === e[0]);
  return [i + 1, ...m.splice(2), ...e.splice(1)];
});
```

Since the resulting array has the same number of entries as arr2 I am calling map on arr2.

Comment: I need some time to understand. It looks like this is what I need.

Comment: which means '...'?

Comment: it is spread syntax it gives the elements of the array.

Comment: The Best! Works very fast, what I needed.

Comment: Great. Feel free to accept it as the best answer. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

you have to add commas in your arr1 statement and add the bracket at the end of the arr2 statement and remove the sort() function.

Comment: Sorry, missed the commas and brackets. Why remove sort()?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).